# Redeployable script in DB2 SQL. Insert a row only If a row doesn't exist

Tags: sql, db2, sql-insert, rollback

I have seen scripts working for SQL server using If not exists.

But I couldn't execute similar script in DB2.

Below link is just an example but not exactly my requirement

[DB2 Drop table if exists equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270937/db2-drop-table-if-exists-equivalent)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274459/db2-insert-row-if-not-exist-with-value-from-parameter Please try this.

Comment: Db2 has a MERGE statement that is even better than those scripts.

Comment: Try the SP db2perf_quiet_drop  referenced here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/db2-equivalent-for-mysqls-drop-if-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2 insert row if not exist with value from parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274459/db2-insert-row-if-not-exist-with-value-from-parameter)

Comment: Your question title does not match the body. Are you after inserting rows into a table, or dropping/creating a table?

Comment: Trying to insert a row . Conditional Insert statement @mustaccio

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you did not provide your table structure and sample data, so I can only guess what they look like, but, as suggested by [data_henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923755/data-henrik), you should probably use the [`MERGE` statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html), something like:

```
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
USING TABLE (VALUES ( 42, 'foo', 'bar')) AS src ( id, val1, val2 )
ON tgt.id = src.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT ( id, col1, col2 ) VALUES ( src.id, src.val2, src.val1 )
```

The above assumes that `target_table.id` is how you determine that "a row doesn't exist". Adjust the condition to include all key columns as necessary.

If your Db2 version, which for some reason you also chose not to disclose, does not yet support the `MERGE` statement, you can simulate the behaviour using the standard `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO target_table tgt ( id, col1, col2 )
SELECT FROM TABLE (VALUES ( 42, 'foo', 'bar')) AS src ( id, val1, val2 )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM target_table WHERE id = src.id
)
```